# Detect router change in angular io

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular io. For one of my task I need to detect the router change event, with router change I will assign a method to my component where I will perform the task. I tried with

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
```

and

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if(event.constructor.name === "NavigationEnd") {
    alert("hello");
  }
});
```

But this causing an error

```
Unexpected value 'Router' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

Comment: Did you import the router module to your app.module?

Comment: import {Router} from '@angular/router';

Comment: Use above line to import

Comment: I see the import in your component, but did you import it in your module?

Comment: import `RouterModule` into `AppModule`